# I'm not sure which input I should use from imported IO class

Tags: java, input, io

I noticed that there are more than a few ways of creating user input in a command line program.

I simply don't know which to choose.

First I was thinking of using an input scanner but then I'm just following the pseudocode of program which includes `import java.io.*;` tag and nothing more.

Which input method should I use from `import java.io.*;` which gives me the ability to not only read `String` but also `double` and `char` values without much trouble?

I was googling ways of doing the input but each site uses a different method, which would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally recommend using a `Scanner` just because it makes everything so easy. If you want to use something from `java.io`, you could use a `BufferedReader` in conjunction with an `InputStreamReader`. Something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter anything: ");
String s = in.readLine();
System.out.println("You entered: " + s);
in.close();
```

Well you get the point. You might have to do some parsing to obtain integers / doubles (using `Integer.parseInt(someString)` / `Double.parseDouble(someString)`) from the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easiest way to pass command line parameters to your application, you can try [Apache commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/).  It makes command-line entry very easy if you are looking for ways to pass parameters/arguments to the command line.